# Variance of a shifted exponential

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, variance

[image]

I am having trouble finding the variance of this distribution.
the mean is 2$\lambda$, but the variance is $\lambda^2$ ?
In the solution, they say $\operatorname{Var}(\bar Y) =\lambda^2 $, I'm really puzzled... Shifting a distribution will not really cause its variance to change right?

Really appreciate any help! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are right, variance is invariant under shifting. Basically, your random variable can be expressed as $Y=X+\lambda$, where $X\sim Exp(1/\lambda)$, hence the expected value is $E[Y]=\lambda + E[X] = 2\lambda$, and the variance is
$$
Var(Y) = Var(X) = \lambda^2
$$